# make_shared() reference counting in C++

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, make-shared

From: A Tour of C++ (Second edition)

13.2.1 unique_ptr and shared_ptr

> Using **make_shared()** is not just more convenient than separately
>   making an object using new and then passing it to a shared_ptr, it is
>   also notably **more efficient** because it **does not need a separate
>   allocation for the use count** that is essential in the implementation
>   of a **shared_ptr**.

**My question**: How come **shared_ptr** does need to allocate memory for reference counting and **make_shared()** not? (Will it allocate it only once there are at least two references to the data?)

### Edit: I haven't noticed the word "seperate" in the text, so my question is irrelevant ,Tough - I would still like to ask why make_shared() is more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shared pointer contains two parts: The pointer to the "object" you have created, and a pointer to a special control block that contains the reference counter and possibly some other meta-data needed.

If you create your own [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) object, these two memory block will be allocated separately. If you use [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) then the function will only make a single allocation for both blocks of memory.

Comment: which means better data locality in the latter? (sequential memory)

Comment: @IdanBanani That's one thing yes. But also, memory allocations are expensive, and multiple allocations can lead to fragmented memory.

Comment: If the object and counter are allocated together, then how does shared_ptr handles the situation when the object should be destroyed but the counter shouldn't because there are weak pointers using it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think Bjarne mentioned on his keynote: "What can C++ do for embedded systems developers?" that malloc can't lead to fragmentation but the corresponding delete will. Is it true?

Comment: @r3musn0x How can it happen? once the ref count equals 0 ,wouldn't both of them be deleted automatically? (<memory> implementation of std::shared_ptr)

Comment: @IdanBanani, it can happen when using weak_ptr.